# Getting filters from database to filter database if no filter query is specified [Express js] [Postgresql] [Knex]

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, knex.js

I am wondering what would be the best option to dinamically get filter array to filter database using knex whereIn.
Should I create one more table in Postgres and separate columns with filter array in it or is there any better sollution?

```
const getSpecialsits = (req, res) => {

const page = req.query.page || 1
const limit = req.query.limit || 28
const city = req.query.city || "All"

pool.select('*')
    .from('person')
    .limit(limit)
    .offset((page - 1) * limit)
    .whereIn('city', city_array)
    .then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

module.exports = {
    getSpecialsits,
};
```

For example here I want to get city array from db.
if (city === "All") then city_array would be scraped from db, it would be scraped from db anyway to check if the city exists.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[knex modify](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#modify) is the way to go, it takes the query builder argument then you can do stuff like:

build filter as array of `{criteria: column, values: ['a','b']}`

```
.modify(queryBuilder => {

    if (filtersArr.length > 0) {
        filtersArr.forEach(({criteria, values}) => {
            queryBuilder.whereIn(criteria, values)

        }
    }
})
```

thats for the dynamic part, as for how to store a set like `all` or maybe `north` collection of cities it's up to you, i have a `null` and `not-null` check on values that does `empty` or `all` filtering, there's more complexity in it like how you need to append the table name before the criteria and group by ids in the end but it looks like this:

```
if (values.includes('null')) {
    queryBuilder.havingNull(criteria)
} else if (values.includes('not_null')) {
    queryBuilder.havingNotNull(criteria)
} else {
    queryBuilder.havingIn(criteria, values)
}
```